# Calculate Limit-cycle trajectory coordinates using Euler Method;

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the following differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x_s} = \gamma y_s + x_s (R_c^2 - x_s^2 -y_s^2) \\
\dot{y_s} = -\gamma x_s + y_s (R_c^2 - x_s^2 -y_s^2)
\end{cases}
$$

that represent the coordinates x and y of a robot following a limit-cycle trajectory, How to use Euler method to find the approximations of ($x_s$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Euler's method and approximations? This is an exactly solvable system. Simply switch to polar coordinates 
\begin{align}
x &= r \, \cos{\theta}\\
y &= r \, \sin{\theta}
\end{align} 
Then the system turns into
\begin{align}
\frac{d r}{d t} &= r \, \big(R - r\big)\big(R + r\big)\\
\frac{d \theta}{d t} &=  - \gamma
\end{align} 
Then $\theta(t) = \theta_0 - \gamma \, t$ and for the limit cycle you have $r(t) \equiv R$, so the periodic solution in Cartesian coordinates is 
\begin{align}
x(t) &= R \, \cos({\theta_0 - \gamma\, t})\\
y(t) &= R \, \sin({\theta_0 - \gamma\, t})
\end{align}